# How to use Case when to check a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, case

I have a column that I wanted to check and create a calculated column, my records are Name and Tag field, the third column is what I wanted to see after the case statement is applied.

```
Name   Tag                                Calculatedcolumn
Jhon   Subject,Privacy                    Subject
Karla  NonPersonal,Privacy                Not Applicable
Luke   Privacy,Data,Agent                 Not Available
```

My Condition is:- First check for 'subject' in tag field, if found put it in a calculated column and end, if 'subject' is not found, check for 'NonPersonal', if found, Put 'Not Applicable' in calculated column. If both 'Subject' and 'NonPersonal' not found, put 'Not Available'.

```
Case 
         when Tag like '%Subject%' then 'Subject'
         When Tag like '%NONPERSONAL%' then 'Not Applicable' 
         else 'Not Available' end as CalculatedColumn
```

But it did not work as I wanted,the result I am getting is duplicate.

```
Name   Tag                                Calculatedcolumn

Jhon   Subject,Privacy                    Subject
Karla  NonPersonal,Privacy                Not Applicable
Karla  NonPersonal,Privacy                Not Available
Luke   Privacy,Data,Agent                 Not Applicable
Luke   Privacy,Data,Agent                 Not Available
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error you are getting and what is your full select statement. Are all the columns the same datatype?

Comment: Maybe you want `then 'Subject'` instead of `then Tag`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated question to show result.

Comment: You really should say `WHEN ',' + Tag + ',' LIKE '%,Subject,%'` etc. because you don't want to false positive on values that _contain_ the search string, and you don't want to false negative when values are at the start or end of the list. You might also consider a more normalized design (a junction table relating tags to names instead of storing an archaic CSV).

Comment: Please show your whole query so people don't have to guess why you're getting the result you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. I think that you want:

```
case 
     when tag like '%Subject%'     then 'Subject'        --> instead of "Tag"
     when tag like '%NonPersonal%' then 'Not Applicable' 
     else 'Not Available' 
end as CalculatedColumn
```

Comment: I have used that logic but it keeps duplicating the records..Please check the result I am getting on top.

Comment: @YonasHaile please provide us with your full query, and notice that if your database or table encoding is binary then the **'%NonPersonal%'** is totally different from **'%NONPERSONAL%'**

Comment: @YonasHaile: this expression just cannot multiply rows. It simply transcodes one value to another - so this answers the question that you have asked. You might want to ask a *new question* for this other problem that you have, providing sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done like this:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN Tag like '%Subject%' THEN 'Subject' 
WHEN Tag like '%NonPersonal%' THEN 'Not Applicable' 
ELSE 'Not Available' END) as CalculatedColumn
```

This works totally fine